# CrossEntropyLoss showing poor accuracy on 2d output

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, softmax, cross-entropy

I'm trying some experiments on a simple neural network that just tries to learn the squares of some random numbers, represented as arrays of decimal digits, code copied below, with changes indicated by comments.

The version using `nn.Softmax(dim=2)` and `criterion = nn.BCELoss()` works fine.

But for situations like this, where the output is N-way classification (in this case, an array of outputs, each of which indicates one of ten decimal digits), `CrossEntropyLoss` is considered ideal, so I made that change. `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` does softmax for you, so I also commented out the `nn.Softmax` line.

And instead of performing slightly better, the result performs much worse; it now maxes out around something like 76% accuracy on the training set, where previously it had reached 100%.

What am I doing wrong? The same substitution worked fine on an even simpler test case https://github.com/russellw/ml/blob/main/compound_output/single.py with the main difference being that case produces only a single N-way output whereas this produces an array of them. Am I misunderstanding how `CrossEntropyLoss` handles shapes, or some such?

```
import random
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader


def oneHot(n, i, s):
    for j in range(n):
        s.append(float(i == j))


size = 12


class Dataset1(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        s = []
        for _ in range(1000):
            a = random.randrange(10 ** size)

            x = []
            for c in str(a).zfill(size):
                oneHot(10, int(c), x)

            y = []
            for c in str(a ** 2).zfill(size * 2):
                y1 = []
                oneHot(10, int(c), y1)
                y.append(y1)

            x = torch.as_tensor(x)
            y = torch.as_tensor(y)
            s.append((x, y))
        self.s = s

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.s)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.s[i]


trainDs = Dataset1()
testDs = Dataset1()

batchSize = 20
trainDl = DataLoader(trainDs, batch_size=batchSize)
testDl = DataLoader(testDs, batch_size=batchSize)
for x, y in trainDl:
    print(x.shape)
    print(y.shape)
    break


class View(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, *shape):
        super(View, self).__init__()
        self.shape = shape

    def forward(self, x):
        batchSize = x.data.size(0)
        shape = (batchSize,) + self.shape
        return x.view(*shape)


hiddenSize = 100


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(size * 10, hiddenSize),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hiddenSize, hiddenSize),
            nn.Tanh(),
            nn.Linear(hiddenSize, hiddenSize),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(hiddenSize, size * 2 * 10),
            View(size * 2, 10),
            #nn.Softmax(dim=2),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)


device = torch.device("cpu")
model = Net().to(device)
print(sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters()))


def accuracy(model, ds):
    n = 0
    for x, y in ds:
        # make input sample shape match a mini batch
        # for the sake of things like softmax that cause the model
        # to expect a specific shape
        x = x.unsqueeze(0)

        # this is just for reporting, not part of training
        # so we don't need to track gradients here
        with torch.no_grad():
            z = model(x)

            # conversely, the model will return a batch-shaped output
            # so unwrap it for comparison with the unwrapped expected output
            z = z[0]

        # at this point, if the output were a scalar mapped to one-hot
        # we could use a simple argmax comparison
        # but it is an array thereof
        # which makes comparison a little more complex
        assert y.shape[0] == size * 2
        assert z.shape[0] == size * 2
        for i in range(0, size * 2):
            if torch.argmax(y[i]) == torch.argmax(z[i]):
                n += 1
    return n / (len(ds) * size * 2)


#criterion = nn.BCELoss()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
epochs = 10000
interval = epochs // 10
for epoch in range(epochs + 1):
    for bi, (x, y) in enumerate(trainDl):
        x = x.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)

        loss = criterion(model(x), y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if epoch % interval == 0 and not bi:
            print(
                f"{epoch}\t{loss}\t{accuracy(model, trainDs)}\t{accuracy(model, testDs)}"
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if it doesn't raise error, `torch.BCELoss` is not actually what you want to minimize because it wrongly interprets your tensors as a multitude of **binary** classifications. Therefore it is a good idea to switch to `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`.

As you can see in its [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) the function takes class number at targets (not one-hot-encoded) and only supports tensor with at most one dimension for the batch. So you can try:

```py
x = x.to(device)
y = y.to(device)
# Flat together the figures prediction in the batch
pred = model(x).reshape(-1, 10)  # shape (batch_size*2*size , 10)
# Reverse one-hot encoding for targets + flat
y = torch.argmax(y, dim=2).reshape(-1) # shape (batch_size*2*size, )
loss = criterion(pred, y)
```

I got 100% training accuracy at epoch 1100 with your config (same architecture, CPU, batch size 20) as you can see:

[image]

Note that the model actually overfits the training data in this scenario but it is an other problem...